# Invoke-RestMethod converts backslash to slash

Tags: rest, powershell

I would like to call a REST API passing a parameter that contains a backslash character.

The API expects a route like `api/test/<app_name>/<user_name>`, and for example I would like to pass `domain\login` as value for `user_name`.

I tried this with PowerShell:

```
$uri = [Uri]::EscapeUriString("http://localhost:5555/api/test/App Name/Domain\login")
# now $uri = 'http://localhost:5555/api/test/App%20Name/Domain%5Clogin'
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Verbose
```

The output of `Invoke-RestMethod` with the `-Verbose` flag shows that PowerShell **is converting the backslash to a slash**, and after that I get a 404 from the REST API (which is expected since the route does not match):

```
VERBOSE: GET http://localhost:5555/api/test/App Name/Domain/login with 0-byte payload
Invoke-RestMethod :
404 Not Found
```

**How can I avoid this behavior and use a path with an encoded backslash?**

Here is the output of my `$PSVersionTable` variable:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.953
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.953
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Interesting. Can reproduce this on windows 100%. On CentOS, \ is converted to `/`, but `%5C` stays `%5C`...

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is that I'm explicitly escaping it and it still gets replaced.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? I'm using 5.1 and my verbose output is `VERBOSE: GET http://localhost:5555/api/test/App Name/Domain%5Clogin with 0-byte payload` which suggests that it's retaining the backslash.

Comment: @Robin: I'm using PS 5.1 as well. I'll update the question with the contents of `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: For completeness, I'm using `PSVersion 5.1.15063.0` and `BuildVersion 10.0.15063.0`. Slightly newer.

Comment: Just ran this in a W10 VM with the same PS version as yourself, and my verbose matches what you've found. I guess this has been fixed in a later version (unless of course, the verbose isn't accurate in saying what it's trying to do).

Comment: @Robin: thanks, I'll try to update the PS version and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know how your API has been written, but are you sure you need to pass your credentials as part of the URL? Wouldn't they be passed through the credentials param?

Answer (score 0):

What should word: replace `/` with `//`
Maybe you must define it as regular String and then convert it:

```
$RawUri = 'http://...'
```

Here you should use `//` instead of `/`.

Then use your code and replace the text with the new variable.